# Invalid date - Number to Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, angularjs-scope

I was trying to convert a Number to Date in Javascript. Below is the code which I have tried

```
    var newDate = new Date(1012256900000);
    console.log("Test: ",newDate.toString('MMM-yyyy'));
```

This is working fine.
But when I get it from $rootScope object, am getting invalid date :(

```
    var newDate = new Date($rootScope.lastLoginTime);
    console.log("Test: ",newDate.toString('MMM-yyyy'));
```

This is printing Invalid Date. FYI, 
$rootScope.lastLoginTime = 1463256900000;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna take a guess here, but look at what I did in the browser console:

```
new Date(1463256900000)
> [date] Sat May 14 2016 21:15:00 GMT+0100

new Date("1463256900000")
> [date] Invalid date
```

Completely wild guess, but perhaps you should ensure you are passing a number, not a string, to `new Date()` - the constructor behaves *very* differently in either case.

Consider instead trying this:

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setTime($rootScope.lastLoginTime);
```

`setTime` takes a numeric argument only, and will convert your string to a number for you if you pass it one.

Comment: Thats perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Guess your `$rootScope.lastLoginTime = '1463256900000';` than `$rootScope.lastLoginTime = 1463256900000;`.

`new Date(time)` does works when time is `number` , not when time is `string`.

```js
var t1 = 1463256900000;
var t2 = '1463256900000';

var d1 = new Date(t1);
var d2 = new Date(t2);

console.info(d1);
console.info(d2);
```

Comment: Well, that response is coming from server(1463074320000). Am assigning it to rootScope variable. I tried to convert it to string, like  var temp = $rootScope.lastLoginTime; temp = temp.toString(); Even now am getting Invalid Date

Comment: Need to convert it to number rather than string